# Building a Conditional Type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to build something where I have a curried function that takes on 2 seq arguments. First would be a message name, and the second the data related to that specific message.

So let's that that I have two types.

```
type One = {
  name: "OneMessage";
  data: {
     name: string;
  }
}

type Two = {
  name: "TwoMessage";
  data: {
     lastName: string;
  }
}
```

genericFN = (message) => (data) => ({message: message, data:data})

And when using the genericFN, when I pass the message name, let's say 
genericFN("TwoMessage"), it would give me back a function that would be waiting for the specific data related to that message, which in this case would be {lastName: string};

I hope I could make myself understand.

And also, for the ones that can see clearly what I'm trying to do, please let me know how would you approach this situation in your head to come up with the solution.

Thanks for your guys time.

Comment: Renan, please check my newer answer. I believe it might provide a solution. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
type Messages = {
    OneMessage: {
        data: {
            name: string
        }
    }
    TwoMessage: {
        data: {
            name: string 
        }
    }
}


const getFunction = <Name extends keyof Messages>  (name:Name) => (data:Messages[Name]["data"]){
    console.log(data)
}
```

for example:

```
getFunction("OneMessage")
```

will return a function that accepts

```
{name:string}
```

Comment: Hi Ben, thank you for you answer, it fits my use case perfectly !

Comment: You check this as the accepted answer and we both gain points :-)

Comment: Haha, I honestly thought that I had clicked on the accepted instead of the upvote. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you would like to do.

`Payload` interface is the common type for `One` and `Two` from your example.

```
interface Payload<TName extends string> {
    name: TName;
    data: DataType<TName>;
}
```

We need to declare a type for `data` property of our `Payload` interface, and here is where we will use conditional types.

```
type DataType<TName> = TName extends 'OneMessage' ? { name: string; } :
    TName extends 'TwoMessage' ? { lastName: string; } :
    never;
```

The last step is to specify types for your `genericFN` function.

```
const genericFN = <TName extends string>(message: TName) =>
    (data: DataType<TName>): Payload<TName> =>
        ({ name: message, data });
```

---

*Please note:* when you call `genericFN`, type system should be aware of what specific string `TName` is, *in compile-time*. If you do not know it, you should do a simple equality check:

```
const someUnknownString: string = getSomeString();
if (someUnknownString == 'OneMessage') {
    const result = genericFN(someUnknownString)({ name: 'John' }); // will work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Messge Types
type One = {
    readonly name: "OneMessage"
    data: {
        name: string,
    },
 }

type Two = DR<{
    readonly name: "TwoMessage";
    data: {
        lastName: string;
    }
 }>

type Message = One | Two

// Functions 
type GenericFunction<name extends Message["name"]> = (
     name extends One["name"]? GFun<One> : GFun<Two>
 )

type GFun <M extends Message> = (param:M) => unknown
```

Now if you declare a function to have the type `GenericFunction<"OneMessage">` it will only accept a param of type message one.

Comment: It is an interesting approach, though it is still not obvious how to declare `genericFN` function